# Hyperlink in Tooltip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

How to create hyperlink in tooltip like in below image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom ToolTip that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip.

There is an example on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/ToolTip_With_Image.aspx) that adds an image to the ToolTip, you should be able to do something similar to add hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a **true** tooltip - That's actually a floating window. You would need to create a window with a hidden border (titlebar etc) and set to "stay on top", then show it when the mouse moves in/out.